# Progressbar dialogue don't dismiss after page loade finished

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

I used code below to show progress bar, but it's not dismissing automatically (But when i touch on screen it dismiss)

N.B: Progress bar dismiss only home page in my webview. not any other page of posts. Please suggest me how to dismiss the progress bar dialogue automatically without touching it.

```
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            wv.loadUrl(mypage_error);}

        //ProgressDialogue
        ProgressDialog pd = null;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.show();

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                            }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow the Progressbar to dismiss ,when you touch,set it like below

```
 pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");

    pd.setCancelable(true);
 pd.show();
```

Comment: Actually it should be `setCancelable(false)` to restrict from dismissing on touch.

Answer (score 0):

```
//ProgressDialogue
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            wv.loadUrl(mypage_error);}


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            pd.show();

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                            }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                            }
```